# Houseplant health diagnosis

Tags: houseplants, watering, leaves, succulents

These mother's tongue (snake plant) potted plants were purchased about about two/three months ago. They have not been repotted yet and it looks like the nursery soil has some time release nutrients in it.

I suspect that the yellow/dying leaves are from under watering, but I'd like to confirm. The tips of the other leaves don't look burned at all.

[image]

Comment: How often do they get water?

Comment: The tag suggested to let dry out more than most plants so I watered until the top half the pots were dry. In the last month, I've switched to watering when one inch from the top dried.

Comment: I water these plant weekly, but with a little bit of water each time. I don't have these symptoms, so it might be an under watering problem.

Comment: Is the top of your soil drying out between waterings or does it remain moist?

Comment: It is drying out as well, I haven't been checking with my fingers, though.

Comment: I used to water mine once a month and it grew like crazy. I used a very well-draining soil (just under 1/2 potting soil, about 1/6 perlite and 1/3 pea gravel). When I did water it, I drenched it and broke standard houseplant 101 by letting it sit in the water in the saucer. The plant lived over 20 years, until I put it in a room that got below 50 degrees F. That killed it.

Comment: All leaves of all plants die.  That doesn't mean in itself there is a problem.  These plants look very happy.  Just cut the dead and dying leaves off.  If you get more, then you have a problem.  These plants love being root bound.  If you transplant them use only potting soil.  Don't make your own soil.  Only bored experts do that.  Grins!  Get used to the heft of the pot and plant after you've watered.  When it needs water again that pot will be noticeably lighter.  When you transplant...someday in potting soil, then you should add a bit of balanced fertilizer.

Comment: @b.nota Shallow watering is great for succulents and cactus.  Sansevieira is not a succulent.  It is one tough plant however.  When watering anything other than succulents/cactus/seed starts deep watering is the only way to go, drain out the bottom of the pot, and dump all excess water.  Feel the heft.  Do not water again until that pot and plant and soil feel light when you lift off the surface.  Deep then allow to dry.  Do not do the shallow watering with this plant.